# Unable to bind Twilio sms with azure functions,

Tags: azure, function, twilio

Unable to successfully bind twilio sms with azure functions, it gives error saying twilio not recognized..

if anyone has any clue what needs to be done here , please post solution with working code, or else
please let me know how to display popup message in azure functions when it is triggered.

using System;
using Twilio;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

```
string accountSid = "SID";
string authToken = "token";

var client = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken);

    client.SendMessage(
        "+from", // Insert your Twilio from SMS number here
        "+to", // Insert your verified (trial) to SMS number here
        "hello from Azure Functions!" + DateTime.Now            
    );
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: using System;
using Twilio;
 
public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");    
 
    string accountSid = "SID";
    string authToken = "token";
 
    var client = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken);
 
        client.SendMessage(
            "+from", // Insert your Twilio from SMS number here
            "+to", // Insert your verified (trial) to SMS number here
            "hello from Azure Functions!" + DateTime.Now            
        );
}

Answer (score 0):

This is Twilio website itself: https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-rain-notifications-from-azure-functions

Comment: below is the code i had used with timer trigger, c an you tell me what needs to done.
as when i run this it states no 'Twilio' namespace found.

Comment: using System;
using Twilio;
 
public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");    
 
    string accountSid = "SID";
    string authToken = "token";
 
    var client = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken);
 
        client.SendMessage(
            "+from", // Insert your Twilio from SMS number here
            "+to", // Insert your verified (trial) to SMS number here
            "hello from Azure Functions!" + DateTime.Now            
        );
}

Comment: Also if you know any alternative , like maybe display a popup message in browser when function is triggered.?

Comment: have not run the code, so don't know here it get stuck. Yes whenever a function gets triggered you can use SignalR to popup on a webpage. or you can use a queue, where in your frontend (Angular,React,.NET) can listen to and show popup.